# How to change the attributes of page elements when cloning in jquery?

Tags: jquery, input, clone, attr

Example:

http://jsbin.com/naqaboga/1/edit?html,js,output

Need to change when cloning "hidden" attribute name = "" and value = "" for input, select, and textarea on the value of i. Thank you.

(click) name="data[group][text][hidden]" to name="data[group][text][0]"

(click) name="data[group][text][hidden]" to name="data[group][text][1]"

Comment: store cloning elem in some var and change the attribute, post what you have trying code for helping better.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set these attributes of elements as as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#group').on('click', '.add_subgroup', function () {
        var i = $('div.subgroup').length;
        var where = $('#group');
        var subgroup = $('#subgroup_hidden').clone();

        var j = i + 1;
        subgroup.attr({
            'id': 'subgroup_' + j,
            'class': 'subgroup'
        }).appendTo(where);

        subgroup.find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
            $(this).attr({
                name: '',
                value: ''
            })
            if($(this).is('textarea'))
                $(this).text('');
        })
        i++;
    });

    $('#group').on('click', '.remove_subgroup', function () {
        $(this).closest('.subgroup').remove();
    });
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wUg8/)